# Laravel query for inbox system

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to make inbox system in Laravel.

CHAT TABLE

```
id | user_from_id |user_to_id | msg_text|read
1  |            2 |         1 |     test|   0
1  |            4 |         1 |     test|   1
1  |            2 |         1 |     test|   0
```

How I can get result like:

That there are messages not read (read = 0) or all is read (read=1), for every user distinct.
For example in this table result should be:

User_from_id = 2 have some unread messages and read is 0;
User_from_id =4 all messages are read;

Comment: So you want to count the number of read and unread messages for each user?

Comment: not just read, I want it to be like email inbox, if there is unread message for user i want to color red div if not to color white and i need some value to find that for each user

Comment: You can just check if the count of unread messages > 0 or not. I think there are many resources online to find out how to do this.

Comment: But can not get the text of the latest message to display from that conversation

Answer (score 0):

Create a ***local scope*** and pass user_id and read as a status to fetch the record and use as you wanna to display.